# How do I access a directive scope from a parent directive/controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a template that goes something like this:

```
<parent-directive>
    <child-directive binding="varFromParent"></child-directive>
    <button ng-click="parentDirective.save()"></button>
</parent-directive>
```

When executing a function in the `parentDirective` controller, is it possible to access and manipulate the scope variables of the `childDirective` for e.g. if I have them set up as so

```
angular.module('app').directive('parentDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '...',
    controllerAs: 'parentDirective',
    controller: function($rootScope, $scope) {
      //...
      this.save = () => {
        //Need to manipulate childDirective so that its
        //scope.defaultValue == 'NEW DEFAULT' 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and

```
angular.module('app').directive('childDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '...',
    scope: {
        binding: '='
    }, 
    controllerAs: 'childDirective',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      scope.defaultValue = 'DEFAULT';
    }
  }
});
```

How would I go about doing this? Is there any way to do this without setting up a bidirectional binding? I would like to avoid a mess of attributes on the `<child-directive>` element if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way to set up a communication between your children and your parent directive:

1. **Bidirectional binding** (like you said)
2. **Registration of your children in your parent**.

   You can use the directive `require` property and the last parameter of the link function `controllers` to register a children in his parent.
3. **Events**, see `$scope.on/broadcast`
4. **Angular services** (as they are "singletons", it's very easy to use it to share data between your directives)

etc.

**Example for 2:**

```
angular.module('Example', [])
.directive('parent', [function () {
    return {
        controller: function (){
            // registerChildren etc
        }
        // ...
    };
}])
.directive('children', [function () {
    return {
        require: ['^^parent', 'children'],
        controller: function (){
            // ...
        }
        link: function ($scope, element, attributs, controllers) {
            ParentController = controllers[0];
            OwnController = controllers[1];
            ParentController.registerChildren(OwnController);
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you probably don't need to isolate child's directive scope. Define a variable you need to change on parent's scope and then child's directive scope would inherit this value so you can change it value in child's directive and it would be accessible from parent.

```
angular.module('app').directive('parentDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controllerAs: 'parentCtrl',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.value = 'Value from parent';
      this.value = $scope.value
      this.save = function() {
        this.value = $scope.value;
      }
    }
  }
});

angular.module('app').directive('childDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controllerAs: 'childCtrl',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.value = 'Value from child';
      this.setValue = function() {
        $scope.value = 'New value from child';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dmitriy_nevzorov/fy31qobe/3/